# css preprocessors with less

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I just started working with less and am trying to work on some simple boxes to get a better understanding. There are 4 boxes with different colors and sizes however on the div:nth-child(2) it always creates two boxes. How can I fix it to make one box?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CSS Preprocessors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="less/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav>Navigation Bar</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

```
*{
  margin: 0;
}

html{
  background-color: @mainColor;

}

.container {
  min-height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

  div:nth-child(1){
    .boxes(@box1Color, 100px)
  }

  div:nth-child(2){
    .boxes(@box2Color, 200px)
  }

  div:nth-child(3){
    .boxes(@box3Color, 250px)
  }

  div:nth-child(4){
    .boxes(@box4Color, 50px)
  }
```

with the container and without the second nth child the page looks completely fine but when the second box is added everything condenses and the a big box goes behind the regular boxes

```
.boxes(@color, @wh){
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: solid black 2px;
  background-color: @color;
  height: @wh;
  width: @wh;
}
```

[boxes in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkijm.png)

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why did you tag this question with Javascript?

Comment: I think LESS is obscuring your problem. Can you reduce it to just HTML and CSS and use the live demo feature of the question editor to display it?

Comment: I am specifically trying to work with LESS

Comment: "the div:nth-child(2) it always creates two boxes" – CSS and LESS don't create any boxes or HTML elements - what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I am creating boxes in div. they work fine when the second nth child is taken out but when I put it in it always creates two boxes instead of just one like the rest

Comment: "everything gets jumbled up" - please clarify what you mean by that. Add **all** clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this selector...

```
div:nth-child(2){
 .boxes(@box2Color, 200px)
}
```

...you should be more specific, since that will apply to *all* DIVs which are a second child of *anything* else.

Use the class of your parent container in a combined selector to limit the selection to children of that container, like this:

```
div.container > div:nth-child(2){
 .boxes(@box2Color, 200px)
}
```

And similar for the other children.

In LESS you can also write that (and your other child-selector rules) as

```
div.container {
  &>div:nth-child(1){
    .boxes(@box1Color, 100px)
  }
  &>div:nth-child(2){
    .boxes(@box2Color, 200px)
  }
  &>div:nth-child(3){
    .boxes(@box3Color, 250px)
  }
  &>div:nth-child(4){
    .boxes(@box4Color, 50px)
  }
}
```

P.S.: Actually, the main mistake in your code is that you are closing the rule for `.container` directly after the settings instead of moving that closing bracket (`}`) to *after*  the rules for the child divs.

*My* LESS code above is also a little bit more specific by also using the *direct child selector*  `>` combined with the `&` placeholder for the parent in the rules for the children.